# JSon editor with schema and references

Tags: text-editor, json, file-format

I'm looking for a Json editor that could assist someone not familiar with json (or any type of code/scripts/data formats) to generate json files following a strict structure. I looked around and found no solution which UI would help someone to actually write json from scratch.

The structure is not really complicated (for now, I hope it stays that way), and I can input it through a schema, script, UI or whatever (I'm a dev). It would be a list of a rather simple item (about 10-15 fields max and 2 lists of 1-5 items)

**What I'd like:**

- Provide a straightforward UI to guide json writing while respecting a given structure. For instance, to have an UI that would provide input fields according the schema.
- Free, but please if you have any suggestion make it, if pricing is reasonable I might buy a license
- Preferably on windows or web app; linux is acceptable. OSX or mobile won't do.
- Nice to have: handle references between items (in any way). For instance, set a field as item reference; and another as a "referencer" leading to another item. Visualizing as graph would be awesome.